# dynamic Getvalue return object cast to PropertyInfo.PropertyType

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting, propertyinfo

My question is: How can make

```
PropertyInfo.GetValue(object, null);
```

return value with casted to PropertyType, not return object.

I tried Convert.ChangeType but not luck.

Thank you.

**Update 1:**

More detail:

My code:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in customerInfo.CustomerRelationship.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var relationshipList = (IList)propertyInfo.GetValue(customerInfo.CustomerRelationship, null);
    foreach (var relationship in relationshipList)
    {
    }
}
```

with

```
public struct CustomerInfo
{
    public Customer CustomerItem { get; set; }
    public Relationship CustomerRelationship { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship
{
    public List<Contact> ContactItems { get; set; }
    public List<Department> DepartmentItems { get; set; }
    ..........
}
```

Because i can't dynamic cast each Relationship Item show i can't compare, query (Linq) manipulate with database .

Comment: `GetValue` will already return a *value* of the correct type. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, correct type but type is object not the exactly class.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

For the sake of simplicity, a generic wrapper can be written over it.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
return (T)PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj1, obj2);
}
```

Comment: For safety, you may want to store the result of GetValue in a local variable, and check whether it really is of type T to ensure (as much as you can) that the cast won't throw an exception.

Comment: as won't necessarily work, since T could be a value type. You can still use is, then do the normal cast if is returns true.